# What is fn* and how does Clojure bootstrap?

Tags: clojure, bootstrapping

The [source for clojure.core](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) appears to assume the pre-existence of `fn*`.  Where is this defined?  What else is needed for bootstrap (over existing Java types)?  How is it all put together?

Maybe this has already been asked?  I am having a hard time getting good search results for `fn*`.

*update:* Changed "bootstrap itself" to "bootstrap" in title, because I didn't want to imply Clojure was self-hosting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java 46 line:

```
static final Symbol FN = Symbol.intern("fn*");
```

fn* implement by clojure compiler, as others special form, I guess.

**Update:**
in analyzeSeq method, 6452-6353 line:

```
    if(op.equals(FN))
        return FnExpr.parse(context, form, name);
```

please check out FnExpr class implement code.