# What is the difference between fn and fn*?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, what is the difference between fn and fn*? I see fn* when I syntax quote a function created with the # macro. For example, in the REPL:

```
user=> `#(inc %)   
(fn* [p1__342__343__auto__] (clojure.core/inc p1__342__343__auto__))
```

Is this simply used for debugging purposes to identify that the function was created by # rather than fn directly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767305/what-is-fn-and-how-does-clojure-bootstrap

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this post on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/clojure/f8iovY57J4k/gO8lhZVq8PEJ) `fn*` is a primitive form to create functions and `fn` is a macro built on top of it to implement higher-level features like destructuring.

Comment: This was a real bitch to find. Googling fn* obviously didn't work. DuckDuckGo came to the rescue though :)