# Why does this anonymous function starting with println result in a NullPointerException?

Tags: clojure

I am learning about `pmap` and wrote the following function:

```
(pmap #((println "hello from " (-> (Thread/currentThread) .getName)) 
         (+ %1 %2)) 
   [1 1 1] [-1 -1 -1])
```

When run, the result is a `NullPointerException`

```
(hello from  clojure-agent-send-off-pool-4
hello from  clojure-agent-send-off-pool-3
hello from  clojure-agent-send-off-pool-5
NullPointerException   user/eval55/fn--56 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:11)
```

Why is this happening?  I have understood and observed the body of a `fn` to be an implicit `do`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The anonymous `fn` literal `#()` does not have an implicit `do`.

Comment: And I see (using `macroexpand`) that `#()` expands to `fn*` not `fn` (the macro).

Comment: So you'd replace #() with fn[x]?

Comment: Either use `(fn [] (println ) ...)` or `#((do (println ...)`

Comment: `fn*` vs `fn` is not relevant here. The difference is that `#((x %))` expands to `(fn [%] ((x %)))`, not to `(fn [%] (x %))`.

Comment: Not sure why you think "not relevant" - just an observation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488479/what-is-the-difference-between-fn-and-fn Also, I had an error: it should be `#(do (println ...`

Answer (score 2):

You have `println` in 2 parens so the result of `println` is evaluated.  `println` always returns nil hence the NullPointerException.

Try removing the extra parens from the `#()`:

```
   (pmap #(println "hello from " 
         (-> (Thread/currentThread) .getName) 
         (+ %1 %2)) 
          [1 1 1] [-1 -1 -1] )
```

EDIT:

Then you will need the `do` as mentioned in other comments like:

```
(pmap #(do (println "hello from " 
     (-> (Thread/currentThread) .getName)) 
     (+ %1 %2)) 
      [1 1 1] [-1 -1 -1] )
```

The reason the `do` is necessary in the `#()` reader macro is not that functions don't include an implicit `do` but has to do with the way the macro expands.  Basically, that macro assumes a single form hence the need for the explicit `do`.

Comment: It expands to: `(fn* [p1__13# p2__14#] (println "hello from " (-> (Thread/currentThread) .getName) (+ p1__13# p2__14#)))`. However, now you've broken the intent of my `pmap` function. Check out the return value.

Comment: What do you want the result to be?