# Is there a difference between the fn and # syntax for anonymous functions in Clojure?

Tags: syntax, clojure, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm new to clojure, and I've seen anonymous functions written like:

```
(fn [x] (* x x))
```

and also like:

```
#(* % %)
```

Obviously, the second is more concise. Is there any relevant difference? Can every anonymous function be represented in either style? Is one more idiomatic?

Related to this question, I was unable to determine how to convert `(fn [x] [x x])` to the latter syntax. I would appreciate a pointer to documentation that clarifies this situation.

Comment: #() does not have an implicit do.  (fn [] ... ) does.

Comment: To elaborate on @Bill's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534287/why-does-this-anonymous-function-starting-with-println-result-in-a-nullpointerex

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most important differences are:

- `(fn ...)` can be nested, `#()` cannot
- You can name your parameters better with `(fn [x y] ..)` or similar, rather than using `%`, `%2`, `%3` etc.
- You can name a function with `(fn ...)` for recursive usage, e.g. `(fn fib [n] (if (<= n 1) 1 (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))`
- It's easier to do code generation/manipulation `(fn [...] ...)` since `#()` is a reader macro rather than a regular Clojure form.
- `#()` is more concise. But if that is a major consideration, you probably have your priorities wrong :-)

Personally my advice would be:

- Prefer `(fn [...] ...)` in most circumstances
- Use `#()` only for very short inline functions, e.g. `(map #(+ 2 %) (range 10))`
- Also consider that it may be better to generate anonymous functions via higher-order functions rather than writing them out explicitly e.g. `(comp func1 func2)` or `(partial func param1 param2)` etc.

Comment: Another limitation worth mentioning (I didn't know if I could/should edit your response) is that `fn` allows you to name your function, so that they can be referenced within the body, as in: `(def fact (fn f [x] (if (= 1 x) 1 (* x (f (dec x))))))`

Comment: Really appreciate the `comp` and `partial` suggestions. I wondered if those were present, having appreciated them in Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

Another SO answer ([Common programming mistakes for Clojure developers to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021343/22417)) mentions that `#([% %])` expands to `fn [%] ([% %])` (note the parentheses), which causes an ArityException.

You can do `#(vector % %)` to workaround this limitation.

Comment: Can't tell you how much time I've wasted because of this one.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://clojure.org/reader), i think that these are the most relevant differences:

> idiomatic used would be for very short one-off mapping/filter fns and the like.
>
> #() forms cannot be nested.

Another thing is that if you need named parameters, fn is a better option. For the #() you will use % or, for more the one parameters, something like %1, %2 and so on (also %&).